# Background image is not displayed properly only on Android browsers

Tags: android, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, viewport

I am trying to create my first responsive web site using bootstrap library on visual 2010.Background of my Login page is an image displayed in the hole page. That's why I have used viewPort to adjust it on mobile phones... 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>` It works fine on all browsers and IOS devices, but for Android devices it is not working properly. There is a white space in the bottom of each Android screen. How can I remove this white space and display the image correctly on android browsers? Attached are 2 screenshots from android and IOS devices.

**Update:**
Below is my css class of my body:

```
.imgBack { 
   background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
   -webkit-background-size: cover; 
   -moz-background-size: cover; 
   -o-background-size: cover; 
    background-size: cover; 
}
```

[image: IOS] [image: Android]

Comment: What css do u use for the background image?

Comment: Please check my update, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add:

```
html{
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
}
body{
    min-height:100%;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion and sorry for the late reply, That solution has resolved half of my problem: sceens on PCs (all browsers) and mobiles (android and IOS) became scrollable  while no need for scroll bar specially when screen is too big (like PCs and tablets screens). Ok for the background it is covering the hole screen but when I scroll down the white space appears again, How can I resolve it? How can I avoid scrolling and fix the screen specially for big size scrrens? I want to enable scrolling only when need it on small screens...

Comment: Ok I sovlved it by removing min height from body and making body background color = transparent